# set value to sql file

Tags: c#, sql

this is my sql file :

```
  USE [master]
GO
DECLARE @DBName nvarchar(50) = ' DataBaseName'
EXEC('ALTER DATABASE ' + @DBName + ' SET READ_ONLY WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE')
GO
```

and I run it with c# code

```
 string sqlConnectionString = txtConstring.Text; //connection string
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path + "Procedure_fn.sql"); //*.sql file path
string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
```

I wonder how can we set the value of the local variable  "DataBaseName" in c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally I'd recommend dropping the variable declaration and other accoutrements from the file completely, so that the *.sql file becomes simply:

> EXEC('ALTER DATABASE ' + @DBName + ' SET READ_ONLY WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE')

And then I'd tell you to call it like this:

```
string script = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(path, "Procedure_fn.sql"));
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(txtConstring.Text))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(script, conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DBName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = "MyDatabaseName";
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
}
```

However, that won't work in this case. Sql Server won't let you use a database name as a parameter. But I did want to bring this up anyway, because when I read your code sample, **it looks like the `Server` type you use is seriously flawed**.

The problem is that it's not clear from the sample that a way exists to safely send parameter information with a query string. Even if such a mechanism exists, it looks like the system is built in a way that encourages using finished sql strings, and is therefore built to encourage extremely unsafe practices. In short, it's just *begging* to get hacked. This is a real and serious problem. The code above demonstrates the correct way to use sql query parameters. If you don't have some mechanism in your database library that supports query parameters that are separate from your sql string, *and that encourages their use over string concatenation,* it's time to get a new database library.

---

That out of the way, what you can do for now is change your file like this:

```
USE [master]
DECLARE @DBName nvarchar(50) = '{0}';
EXEC('ALTER DATABASE ' + @DBName + ' SET READ_ONLY WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE');
```

You need to remove the `GO` lines, because "GO" is **not** part of the sql language. The feature is provided by Management Studio and other query tools, but Sql Server itself *will not understand it*, and so it will cause a syntax error on the server if you leave them in. Also notice what I used for the database name. When that's done, update your code like this:

```
string script = string.Format(File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(path, "Procedure_fn.sql")), "MyDBName");
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(txtConstring.Text))
{
    Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
    server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
}
```

But again, if what I'm seeing in your database library is exemplary of how it works, you need to rethink how you send data to your database. Sql Injection is a real and serious problem that *will* get your application hacked.

Comment: Actually, the `GO`s indicate where the script should be broken into separate commands within the same session (connection).  Though in this case it may work anyway because the last command is dynamic SQL.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Yes, that is what `GO` means: but it means that to Management Studio, not to Sql Server. Sql Server itself doesn't know anything about "GO", and if things are working right never sees that text.

Comment: Joel is correct though, `GO` is not a TSQL command, it used by OSQL etc to send the TSQL lines before the GO as a single batch to SQL Server.  The `GO` itself is never sent to SQL Server.

Comment: Right, I wasn't disagreeing with that part.  I was just saying that in general, if you just take out the `GO`s, most scripts won't work like this.  The `GO`s indicate where the batch command compilation boundaries are supposed to be, so executing the SQL script as all one command (or alternately as all separate commands) won't normally work.

Comment: Yes, especially if there are ALTER statements in the script, you want to make sure you're breaking apart your batches as suggested by the "GO" hints.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to modify the string

```
script = script.Replace("@DBName nvarchar(50) = ' DataBaseName'", 
                        "@DBName nvarchar(50) = ' NEWDATABASENAME'" /* Put new db name here */);
```

Comment: Even better if he sets his default database name to "`{0}`", so that the code would work with `String.Format()`